# Why is the time stamp not used for conflict resolution?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

The docs state that the "winner" is chosen in an arbitrary and consistent fashion. Why is the "later" revision not always chosen? I am sure that the timestamp is present in the payload.

Comment: "Why" questions are not on-topic here, as they're a matter of opinion (in this case: the opinion of the CouchDB authors).  What is on-topic is "How", as in "How do I work around this?" or "How can I use timestamps for conflict resolution?"

Comment: That said, I can offer some speculation:  1. Timestamps are problematic; they depend on precise clock synchronization, which is impractical. 2. You could still have two identical timestamps, so you'd need some other mechanism anyway. 3. Documents don't include timestamps. 4. Which timestamp would you use in a mult-master system anyway? 5. In the end, timestamps are just as arbitrary as anything else. If you need intelligent conflict resolution, you must do it yourself, regardless of the automated mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple add-ons that implement this. Unfortunately not well advertised.

https://github.com/automerge/automerge

https://github.com/redgeoff/delta-pouch

This issue has some discussion:

https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/8163

Looks like pouchdb folks do not read SO.